# How do I stop Intellij from skipping tests?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij to test the following code:

```
// tag::init[]
fun <A> length(xs: List<A>): Int =
    foldRight(xs,0, {_, acc -> 1 + acc} )
// end::init[]

class Exercise_3_8 : WordSpec({
    "list length" should {
        "!calculate the length" {
            length(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) shouldBe 5
        }
            "!calculate zero for an empty list" {
            length(Nil) shouldBe 0
        }
    }
})
```

Testing started at 9:23 a.m. ...

```
> Task :kaptGenerateStubsKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :kaptKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :kaptGenerateStubsTestKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :kaptTestKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
7 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 6 up-to-date
9:23:18 a.m.: Task execution finished ':test --tests "chapter3.exercises.Exercise_3_8"'.

Tests ignored: 2 of 2 tests
```

How do I get the tests to run?

Comment: how are you executing the Gradle tasks? If it's via IntelliJ, can you show the run configuration for that Gradle execution?

Comment: Do you have any tests annotated with @Ignore?

Comment: Here is where I got the source code from:  (https://github.com/fpinkotlin/fpinkotlin).  No, I can't find any @Ignore anywhere.

Comment: from the README in this repo: `Each unit test has been ignored, and can be re-enabled by removing the ! prefix in the test methods while implementing the exercises in a TDD fashion`

Comment: Thanks!  I should read the docs first. ,,